# What's the proper regex for removing "?()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regression

I am trying to remove **?,() and "** from the below string my initial matches are working but for these 3 it not matching kindly suggest what is the issue here

```
data = "(The rain - :in  ,Spain?)"

regexpat =  re.sub(r"'|,|;|.|:|/?|-|(|)", "", name)
```

I need all the special chars removed or replaced with blank

I tried with

```
-|:|\)|\?|
```

but substitution is breaking with this output *

```
*"*(*T*h*e* *r*a*i*n* ** **i*n* * *,*S*p*a*i*n***"*
*
```

Expected Output is

**`The rain in Spain`**

trying here - https://regex101.com/r/Ozsnzv/1

Comment: You have to escape the dot, and you might shorten it to `[',;.:/?()-]` https://regex101.com/r/S0JVtR/1

Comment: not helping remains same

Comment: What type of output exactly you want can you update it in code?

Comment: @MombaChomba See https://ideone.com/wPVwwS

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class to shorten the pattern, and escape the dot to match it literally.

Using `/?` in an alternation matches an optional `/`, but you can just add the `/`to the character class. If you also meant to match `?` you can also add that one.

Then change possible double spaces gaps to single spaces.

**Note** to use `data` instead of `name` in the call to re.sub.

```
import re

data = "(The rain - :in  ,Spain?)"
regexpat = re.sub(r"[',;.:/?()-]+", "", data)

print(' '.join(regexpat.split()))
```

Output

```
The rain in Spain
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wPVwwS).

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

data = "(The rain - :in  ,Spain?)"

regexpat = re.sub(r"[',;.:/?()-]", "", data)
regexpat = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", regexpat)

print(regexpat)  # The rain in Spain
```

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but you seem to want to replace all punctuation. One way is to use the 'punctuation' attribute from the built-in string library:

```
import string
data = "(The rain - :in  ,Spain?)"
regexpat  = data.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
print(' '.join(regexpat.split()))
```

Prints:

```
The rain in Spain
```

---

**Note:** The punctuation attribute includes: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ and therefor may be too extensive compared to your current character class. If however this is what you are after it seems to be [faster than regex](https://datagy.io/python-remove-punctuation-from-string/).